# Adding dynamic picture elements to mapbook

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, image, data-driven-pages

I have a feature class full of traffic signal data including up to 3 pictures of each traffic signal.  I want to create a series of data driven pages that include 3 picture/data frames that dynamically update the pictures based on HTML link in the attribute table.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your version of ArcMap? (I assume that is what you are using.)

Comment: I have ArcGIS 10.  It turns out this function was added with 10.1.  I'm going to update to 10.1 so I should be good.  Thanks.